# Spark regexp_extract to extract informations containing backslash

Tags: regex, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, backslash

I have a problem to extract informations in column from dataFrame containing backslash character.

Here, an example of data in my dataFrame:

| id | repo_path |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | \folder1\folder2\folder3 |
| 2 | \folderA\folderB\folderC\folderD |
| 3 | \folder5\folder6\folder7 |

I want to split the column values in repo_path by "\" and get the values until the first level :

The Output that I want is in column split_path :

| id | repo_path | split_path |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | \folder1\folder2\folder3 | \folder1 |
| 2 | \folderA\folderB\folderC\folderD | \folderA |
| 3 | \folder5\folder6\folder7 | \folder5 |

I have tried differents approachs.

- Using SQL with spark :

```
spark.sql("select df.*, regexp_extract(repo_path, '(\\(\w*){2})',1) as split_path from myDataFrame")
```

This request works but returns an empty column, not my desired results

- 2nd approach :

```
df = myDataFrame.withColumn('split_path', regexp_extract(col('repo_path'), '(\\(\w*){2})',1))
```

This doesn't work and I have an error : *An error occurred while calling o113.showString. Unmatched closing ')' near index 6*

NB : the regular expression seems to be correct because I have tried it in a SQL request executed in Athena database. And I get the desired results.

Anyone have an Idea ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: It seems like you are missing double escaping: one for python strings and one for db. Also you regex seems strange, try `(\\\\\\w*)` with `.sql`

Comment: @markalex : thanks for your help. I'm trying this regexp_extract(v_path,'(\\\\\\w*)',1) in my sql request but I obtain an empty column

Comment: @markalex : your regular expression works. Before, I had to activate this conf in my spark context : spark.conf.set("spark.sql.parser.escapedStringLiterals", "true"). I have an other question. If I want the second level of the repo_path, what is the appropriate regular expression ? Example : For the line with id = 1, the desired result is folder2

Comment: Without `\ ` in the beginning?

Comment: @markalex : yes with \ in the beginning. And I have a solution : regexp_extract(v_path,'(\\\\\\w*){2}'). Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to extract name of the first folder in path with `\` in the beginning:

```py
spark.sql("select df.*, regexp_extract(repo_path, '(\\\\\\w*)', 1) as split_path from myDataFrame")
```

Additionally, you can get any part of path by this (changing 2 for needed number):

```py
spark.sql("select df.*, regexp_extract(repo_path, '(\\\\\\w*){2}', 1) as split_path from myDataFrame")
```

Comment: thanks again for your answer. I just have a last question. If the folder name contains special character such as forward slash, colon, +, etc.. The regular expression does not work. How to adapt it to include these characters

Comment: @Gon, try `\\\\\[^\\]*`. In general, I recommend regex101.com: there you could check your regexes on you sample data.